# How can I prevent a ParseError in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, syntax, controller

src/Controller/DataTableController.php

```
<?php

use DataTables\DataTablesInterface;

/**
 * Symfony 3.4 and above
 *
 * @Route("/users", name="users")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param DataTablesInterface $datatables
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function usersAction(Request $request, DataTablesInterface $datatables): JsonResponse
{
    try {
        // Tell the DataTables service to process the request,
        // specifying ID of the required handler.
        $results = $datatables->handle($request, 'users');

        return $this->json($results);
    }
    catch (HttpException $e) {
        // In fact the line below returns 400 HTTP status code.
        // The message contains the error description.
        return $this->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode());
    }
}

/**
 * Symfony 3.3 and below
 *
 * @Route("/users", name="users")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function usersAction(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    try {
        /** @var \DataTables\DataTablesInterface $datatables */
        $datatables = $this->get('datatables');

        // Tell the DataTables service to process the request,
        // specifying ID of the required handler.
        $results = $datatables->handle($request, 'users');

        return $this->json($results);
    }
    catch (HttpException $e) {
        // In fact the line below returns 400 HTTP status code.
        // The message contains the error description.
        return $this->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

I get the error message:

[image]

Comment: Did you look at line 14 in your file? your are missing the "class DataTableController 
{" tag

Comment: No namespace aswell, maybe start with some starter Symfony tutorials to get to know the basics: https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure for a class, (not related to Symfony) is

```
class MyClassController() {

  public function myMethodAction() {
  }
}
```

There is not way to avoid a parse error because this is just not valid syntax of PHP.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand!